# react-router deploying non-static

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Is it OK to deploy a `react-router` based webapp to production running under a `node.js` server? Deploying static files prevents links like `server.com/about` from working unless `index.html` is loaded first. One can get around this by using `HashRouter` but it seems old school to do down that route.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './js/App';
import About from './js/About';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
    <App>
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    </App>
  </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use nginx fall back any route (eg. server.com/about) to the index.html

for example

```
location ^~ / {
        alias /usr/local/theapp/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/acces.web.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/error.web.log debug;
}

# assets
location ~ ^/.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
       alias /usr/local/theapp/dist;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/theapp/error.web.log debug;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as all routes now fallback to `index.html`. I need the ability to open the about page when a user clicks a link to `example.com/about`.

Comment: But what is `example.com/about`? is it react-router route? or it's a static independent route (eg.  serve from node js controller)

Comment: `example.com/about` is a `Route`.

Comment: if it's `react-router` route falling back to index the react-router it self should handle the `/about` for you and load the proper componer... you need to provide more details (code)

Comment: `react-router` doesn't seem to be handling the route after falling back to index. The the hack below. I've updated the post with original code though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but resolving to something like this alongside the nginx `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` does the trick.

```
class OnLoadHack extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { location, match, history } = this.props;
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && !match.isExact){
        history.push(location.pathname + location.search)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App>
        <Route path='/' component={OnLoadHack} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    </App>
  </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```